# Difference between MimeMessage and SMTPMessage Java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I was developing a mail App in java i can use MimeMessage or SMTPMessage to create a message i can see both have same functions. I googled about the difference but can't find any convincing answer. So can anyone explain what is the difference between both of them.

Answer (score 3):

MimeMessage represents the common attributes of a MIME message used for both sent messages and received messages.  SMTPMessage adds attributes that can be used when constructing a message to be sent via SMTP.  All of the SMTPMessage attributes can be set as properties on the JavaMail Session, which for most cases is sufficient and allows the use of MimeMessage for sent messages.